# MySQL Divide two rows and add into new column

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL table in which I want to perform following operation.

```
ID     Com      Com_Sub Year    Parameter       Value
6       A       A1     2010     Profit      33766.18
20      A       A1     2010     Revenues    2793617.12
30      A       A1     2011     Profit      84310.73
54      A       A1     2009     Profit      129129.5284
60      A       A1     2011     Revenues    2049157.294
70      B       B1     2010     Profit      3753765490
76      B       B1     2010     Revenues    217326.7561
```

Now I need to manipulate it and make it like this

```
ID     Com      Com_Sub Year    Parameter       Value          New Value
6       A        A1     2010    Profit         33766.18       0.0123
20      A        A1     2010    Revenues       2793617.12
30      A        A1     2011    Profit         84310.73       0.0252
54      A        A1     2009    Profit         129129.5284    
60      A        A1     2011    Revenues       2049157.294
70      B        B1     2010    Profit         3753765490     1.235
76      B        B1     2010    Revenues       217326.7561
```

this means whenever I have common Year and Common Com_sub value in the row I need to add the division of both the values.

Comment: What do you mean by "first row"? How the order is defined? Is it possible to have more than 2 rows with the same `c1`?

Comment: I have updated the data.. please c..

Comment: So do you need to divide `Profit` by `Revenues`?

Comment: Yeas.. and add it to the profit row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the table is called `nanuet`, this should do it:

```
alter table nanuet add newvalue decimal(6,2);

update nanuet n1 join nanuet n2 on n1.c1=n2.c1
    set n1.newvalue = n1.value/n2.value
    where n1.id<n2.id;
```

If there are more than 2 rows with the same value of `c1` the results will be hard to predict.

Comment: The logic is the same. Just reverse the name-mangling you had done originally.

Answer (score 0):

```
    UPDATE tbl t1
       SET t1.new_col_name = t1.Value / t2.Value
INNER JOIN tbl t2 ON t2.Com_Sub = t1.Com_Sub
                 AND t2.Year = t1.Year 
                 AND t2.Parameter = 'Revenues'
     WHERE t1.Revenues = 'Profit'
```